# Can I run more than one GPU on my motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu

Seems like my motherboard is this one:

- Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
- Product: Z87-EXPERT
- Serial Number: 130410806800081
- Version: Rev 1.xx

I found out about this from [this](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z87EXPERT/) link here.

It says that there is "3-Way CrossFireX Support". What does that mean?
How many GPUs can I have on it?
I got one GTX 960 atm, I wanted to put at least two or three GTX 1070 on it (without the GTX 960). 
Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes but if you don't have a really good reason (that is not gaming) for that just save for a single 1080TI and you will probably be better off. Triple Crossfire would be AMDs version of SLI.

Comment: Thanks. But Triple Crossfire means I can use three AMD cards, right? What about Nvidia's?

Comment: You read the whole description instead of just bits and pieces and will find a part that says `Quad-GPU SLI and 3-Way CrossFireX Support`. Of course with three PCIx16 slots you can't really go for a quad setup. In addition the clearance might be insufficient as the second slot looks like it might just be 2 slots high. Still, running SLI or CrossFire is a bad idea in most cases anyway. What do you plan to use the setup for?

Comment: Holy! I totally missed this SLI information. Thanks! So in theory I can handle 4 GPUs.. I see. I wanted to have at least two 1070 because I was baited into this crypto-mining shit and wanted to play around. It's not like two 1070 would hurt my wallet, I just wanted to know if it was indeed possible.

Comment: Yes, in theory. It only has three slots. So practically you will not able able to run four discrete graphic cards but a max of three. What they might be including is dual GPU cards. So with just two cards you'd have four chips. But just to mention it again: SLI is a bad idea in most cases. For crypto currency usually AMD/ATI is preferred.

Comment: Yes Indeed AMD is the favorite one but it's because of ETH Mining. The algorithm I was using with the currency I thought on mining was showing better performance with Nvidia cards. That's why I chose a 1070 tbh. :P

Comment: It is worth pointing out 3-way and 4-way SLI isn't officially supported by Nvidia newest GPUs.  Of course it also does not matter because you wouldn't want to use SLI for cryptomining anyways.

Comment: Why is SLI an issue for mining? SLI is Single Line Interlace, a drawing technique. In other words, for real video output.

Comment: @MSalters - Somebody else brought up the SLI, I assume because of CrossfireX, I was just pointing out that more then 2-way SLI isn't currently supported.

Answer (score 3):

> It says that there is a "3-Way CrossFireX Support.  What does that mean? "

It simply means, you can install 3 individual AMD graphic cards, and configure them in a 3-way AMD CrossfireX configuration.  All other requirements for CrossFireX support must be satisfied.

> How many GPUs can I have on it?

Your motherboard specifically supports a 3-way CrossFireX configuration.  This means it at the minimum can support 3 PCI-E GPUs.

> I got one GTX 960 atm, I wanted to put at least two or three GTX 1070
>   on it (without the GTX 960). Is it possible?

You will indeed be able to install 3 individual Nvidia GPUs.  Considering the [motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z87EXPERT/specifications/) you have selected only has 3 PCIe 3.0 expansion slots I wouldn't attempt to install more then 3 PCIe GPUs.  The other 4 PCIe expansion slots are not suitable for GPUs.

> ### Expansion Slots
>
> 3 x PCIe 3.0/2.0 x16 (x16 or dual x8 or x8/x4/x4)
>
> 4 x PCIe 2.0 x1